# Idiom for "wanting to win without doing the work"

Tags: american-english, idiom-requests

I can't think of them right now, but there are some really hilarious ones. Please halp

Comment: "looking for an easy way out" would be getting out of a heap of responsibility without doing the work it should entail .  "shortcut" comes to mind  (or more "there is no shortcut to success" )

Comment: Sounds like someone who likes to 'build castles in the air.'

Answer (score 1):

You want to "have your cake and eat it too". There are many similar to this in other languages provided in the Wikipedia link. Some are quite funny, as you say, if that component of meaning is important.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_can%27t_have_your_cake_and_eat_it